# Swift 5 dynamic type for array

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following code in Swift:

```
class VolumeData <T> {
   private var volume: [T]

   init(with data:Data, width: UInt32, height: UInt32, depth: UInt32) {
      let size = width * height * depth
      volume = data.arrayFromData(size: Int(size))
   }
 }

class Volume: NSObject {

    private var rawVolume : Data?
    public var volume : VolumeData<Any>?
    public var header: Header?

 ....

    func loadVolume(_ name: String) {
        let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "vol")
        rawVolume = try? Data.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath ?? ""))
        header = Header.init(from: ((rawVolume?.subdata(in: 0..<284))!))
        let volSize = header!.width * header!.height * header!.depth
        switch header!.type {
        case .FLOAT:
             volume = VolumeData<Float32>(with: (rawVolume?.subdata
             (in: 284..<volSize))!, width: header!.width, 
             height: header!.height, depth: header!.depth)
        default:
            volume = nil
        }
    }
}
```

And for the sake of completion:

```
extension Data {
    func arrayFromData<T> (size: Int) -> [T] {
       var arr:[T] = []
       for i in 0..<size {
           let offset = 4*i
           let d:T = self[offset..<offset+4].withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
           arr.append(d)
        }
        return arr
    }
}
```

Right now I have a compile-time error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'VolumeData<Float32>' (aka 'VolumeData<Float>') 
  to type 'VolumeData<Any>?'
```

Anyone can point me the correct way to implement this kind of dynamic generics in Swift?

Comment: change your volume data declaration to generic as well

Comment: Maybe you could change public var volume : VolumeData<Any>? to public var volume : VolumeData<Element>?

Comment: @LeoDabus In this case it's problematic because I only know the type after I read the volume.

Comment: Then it cannot be a compile time generic.

Comment: @ppaulojr I might be wrong, but what you want is impossible to implement in Swift or possible with some workarounds that I don't know about. It's impossbile because Swift want's to know all types on compilation step and doesn't allow to create generic with metatype (you cannot create `let c = [String.self, Int8.self, Int.self]` and then `let a = VolumeData<c.first!>()`). Please someone from higher echelon correct me.

Comment: What do you envision doing with VolumeData? As written, it has no way to read the data or manipulate it. How this is addressed is entirely dependent on what kinds of algorithms you envision applying to VolumeData. Broadly, the way that you design this kind of generic data structure is to start with several concrete implementations, and abstract it back to a more generic form; starting with the generic form will just get you into a box. Say it worked exactly like you'd like it to. What would the consuming code look like for a real use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert between `VolumeData` types, you can always use `map` on items and cast:

```
class VolumeData<T> {
    private var volume: [T]

    init(with data: Data, width: UInt32, height: UInt32, depth: UInt32) {
        let size = width * height * depth
        volume = data.arrayFromData(size: Int(size))
    }

    private init(volume: [T]) {
       self.volume = volume
    }

    func convert<TargetType>(conversionFn: (T) -> TargetType) -> VolumeData<TargetType> {
        return VolumeData<TargetType>(volume: self.volume.map(conversionFn))
    }
}
```

then

```
case .FLOAT:
    let floatVolume = VolumeData<Float32>(
         with: (rawVolume?.subdata(in: 284..<volSize))!,
         width: header!.width, 
         height: header!.height,
         depth: header!.depth
    )
    volume = floatVolume.convert { $0 as Any }
```

However, `VolumeData<Any>` is not very useful, it's not useful at all. In this case it would be better to save the original type somehow. One simple method is an `enum` with associated values, e.g.:

```
enum VolumeDataType {
   case float(volume: VolumeData<Float32>)
}
```

and then:

```
class Volume: NSObject {

    private var rawVolume: Data?
    public var volume: VolumeDataType?
    public var header: Header?

    func loadVolume(_ name: String) {
        let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "vol")
        rawVolume = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath ?? ""))
        header = Header(from: ((rawVolume?.subdata(in: 0..<284))!))
        let volSize = header!.width * header!.height * header!.depth

        switch header!.type {
        case .FLOAT:
             volume = .float(volume: VolumeData<Float32>(
                 with: (rawVolume?.subdata(in: 284..<volSize))!,
                 width: header!.width, 
                 height: header!.height,
                 depth: header!.depth
             ))
        default:
           volume = nil
        }
    }
```